# Approximation of a complex-valued function of real variable

Tags: fourier-transform

I have a problem to approximate a complex-valued function of a real argument. In other words, how to find a function’s analytic form in the complex domain if the sets of values of a function of z=x+yi type and arguments n are given.
Thus, if the sequences of real arguments (n) and complex-valued functions (z=x+yi) are given so that n is a set of real numbers, for the simplicity, say integers, and z is a set of complex numbers of (a+bi) type, is it possible to recover (approximate) the analytic form of the function
z = f(n) in any type of approximation. Note that x=f1(n) and y=f2(n), by the definition of a complex-valued function of a real variable.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What exactly do you mean by "analytical function". Do you need a closed form expression, a numerical approximation or something with the Hilbert Transform (which creates analytical signals).? Why can't you just split the complex problem into two separate real problems ?

Answer (score 1):

The analytic signal is given as:

$$x_a(t) = x(t) + j \hat x(t)$$

Where

$x_a(t)$ is the complex analytic signal

$x(t)$ is a real signal

$\hat x(t)$ is the Hilbert transform of $x$.

Thus in the context of the OP's question, the real argument is the function $x(t)$ such that "x=f1(n)" is simply "x=x" and the imaginary component is the Hilbert transform of x such that "y=f2(n)" is the Hilbert Transform itself.

The Hilbert Transform is the result of convolving the function $x(t)$ (typically real, but need not be) with $1/(\pi t)$ and is often done instead in the frequency domain due to the simplification of doing a product instead of convolution. Further, in the frequency domain, the Hilbert Transform is simply multiplying by $-j$ when the frequency is positive, or by $j$ when the frequency is negative.

[image: Hilbert Transform]